# Spring security authorizeExchange and authorizeRequests difference

Tags: spring, spring-security, webflux

when use spring security web, we can use the antMathcers

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**")
```

when use webflux, we use

```
http.authorizeExchange(exchanges->
                        exchanges
                                .pathMatchers("/admin/**")
                                .permitAll()
                                .anyExchange()
                                .authenticated()
)
```

the problem is, the first way we can has the ant patterns like
`"/admin/**/test"`

but the second way, the above method will get wrong.

How can I achieve th above uri pattherns in the webflux environment?

Comment: Can you share what the expected behaviour is compared to what you're seeing? It's not clear which endpoints the WebFlux configuration is getting wrong.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana I hope the webflux to support /admin/**/test pattern, but it only support the ** at the end, like /admin/**

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to AntPathMatcher, is supported only at the end of a pattern. For example is valid but is not. The same applies also to the capturing variant . The aim is to eliminate ambiguity when comparing patterns for specificity. `**/pages/{**}/pages/{**}/details{*spring}`

More Examples:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html